# Unknown protocol error, using TSN devices as a relay unit in omnet++ (without using switches or routers)

Tags: c++, omnet++, inet

I have created a simple network for relaying or forwarding UDP packets from one device to another.
The .ned for my network is as mentioned below:

```
import inet.node.ethernet.EthernetLink;
import inet.node.ethernet.Eth100M;
import inet.networklayer.configurator.ipv4.Ipv4NetworkConfigurator;
import inet.node.inet.StandardHost;

network UdpExample
{
    @display("bgb=655,369");
    submodules:
        configurator: Ipv4NetworkConfigurator {
            parameters:
                @display("p=100,100;is=s");
        }
        client: StandardHost {
            parameters:
                @display("p=250,100");
        }
        server: StandardHost {
            parameters:
                @display("p=544,100;i=device/pc2");
        }
        relay: StandardHost {
            @display("p=402,100");
            forwarding = default(true);
        }
    connections:
        client.ethg++ <--> EthernetLink {  datarate = 100Mbps; } <--> relay.ethg++;
        relay.ethg++ <--> EthernetLink {  datarate = 100Mbps; } <--> server.ethg++;
}

import inet.common.scenario.ScenarioManager;
import inet.node.tsn.TsnDevice;
import inet.networks.base.TsnNetworkBase;
import inet.node.ethernet.Eth100M;

network UdpExample1 extends TsnNetworkBase
{
    parameters:
    @display("bgb=2230.5361,1700.952");
    
    
    submodules:
        tsnDevice1: TsnDevice {
            @display("p=991.728,620.256");
        }
        tsnDevice2: TsnDevice {
            @display("p=1359.792,620.256");
            forwarding = default(true);
        }
        tsnDevice3: TsnDevice {
            @display("p=1751.712,620.256");
        }
        scenarioManager: ScenarioManager {
            @display("p=98.736,839.25604");
        }

    connections:

        tsnDevice1.ethg++ <--> Eth100M <--> tsnDevice2.ethg++;
        tsnDevice2.ethg++ <--> Eth100M <--> tsnDevice3.ethg++;
}
```

The first network is using a "StandardHost", while the second one is using "TsnDevice".For the networks the "relay" and "tsnDevice2" has forwarding = true as shown in the .ned file.

The .ini file for this network is:

```
[Config exp1]
sim-time-limit = 3s

network = UdpExample
*.*.eth[*].bitrate = 100Mbps
*.client.numApps = 1
*.client.app[0].typename = "UdpSourceApp"
*.client.app[0].display-name = "video-Device1"
*.client.app[0].io.destAddress = "server"
*.client.app[0].io.destPort = 1000
*.client.app[0].source.packetLength = 1000B 
*.client.app[0].source.productionInterval = 1ms

# server applications
*.server.numApps = 1
*.server.app[0].typename = "UdpSinkApp"
*.server.app[0].io.localPort = 1000


[Config exp2]

network = UdpExample1
sim-time-limit = 2s

*.tsnDevice2.hasIncomingStreams = true
*.tsnDevice2.hasOutgoingStreams = true

#Ethernet links are 100Mbps
*.*.eth[*].bitrate = 100Mbps

#source
*.tsnDevice1.numApps = 1
*.tsnDevice1.app[0].typename = "UdpSourceApp"
*.tsnDevice1.app[0].source.packetNameFormat = "%M->tsnDevice1:-%c"
*.tsnDevice1.app[0].source.packetLength = 175B
*.tsnDevice1.app[0].source.productionInterval = 1ms 
*.tsnDevice1.app[0].io.destAddress = "tsnDevice3"
*.tsnDevice1.app[0].io.destPort = 1004
*.tsnDevice1.app[0].source.initialProductionOffset = 1ms


#client
*.tsnDevice3.numApps = 1
*.tsnDevice3.app[0].typename = "UdpSinkApp"
*.tsnDevice3.app[0].display-name = "tsnDevice1"
*.tsnDevice3.app[0].io.localPort = 1004
```

The first network works without any issue but the second one(which uses tsn devices) pops this issue:

```
<!> handlePacket(): Unknown protocol: protocolId = 24, protocolName = ethernetmac, servicePrimitive = INDICATION, pathStartGate = combNetwork.tsnDevice2.ipv4.ip.queueOut, pathEndGate = combNetwork.tsnDevice2.ipv4.lp.in[1] -- in module (inet::MessageDispatcher) combNetwork.tsnDevice2.ipv4.lp (id=258), at t=0.00101837s, event #16
```

I'm new to using the omnet++ simulator, and it's possible that the problem has already been resolved. Could someone assist me in resolving the error or guide me on the necessary changes to be made in the .ini file?

Comment: [tag:omnet++]: component-based C++ simulation library. Why do you tag it C?

Comment: According to presented `omnetpp.ini` In the second network (i.e. for the section [Config exp2]) network called `combNetwork` is used. However, presented NED file does not contain that network. Could you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77870535/edit) the question and add the code of the missing network?

Comment: oh my bad , i had done some last min. changes. i have changed it now.

Comment: No you did not fixed it. At least the question is still inconsistent. The error message indicates that combNetwork was used in the run, while your main NED file does not show that network. The two network definitions you are showing are totally unrelated and does not provide any information at all.

Answer (score 0):

First of all remove the line `forwarding = default(true)` from parameters of `tsnDevice2` in NED file. That parameter means that the host forwards IP packets processed in a Layer 3 (i.e. network layer). However, TSN is a Layer 2 technology.
Moreover, change the type of `tsnDevice2` to `TsnSwitch` - a dedicated switch for TSN.
So you should modify your NED file as below:

```
import inet.node.tsn.TsnSwitch;
// ...

tsnDevice2: TsnSwitch {
    @display("p=1359.792,620.256");
    //forwarding = default(true);
}
// ...
```